# Why do I get a timeout from XEmacs gnuclient on LAN?

Tags: networking, emacs, emacsclient

I have a running XEmacs (and gnuserv) on host A. I start gnuclient from bash on host B but get a timeout (end of strace output see below). Both hosts are in the file pointed to by $GNU_SECURE_FILE. This is on a LAN, I never had problems before on different LANs.

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(46602), sin_addr=inet_addr("172.20.9.11")}, 16) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
dup(2)                                  = 4
fcntl(4, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 15), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fcf4396c000
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
write(4, "gnuclient: Connection timed out\n", 32gnuclient: Connection timed out
) = 32
close(4)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fcf4396c000, 4096)            = 0
write(2, "gnuclient: unable to connect to "..., 39gnuclient: unable to connect to remote
) = 39
exit_group(1)                           = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the timeout was that the display wasn't set correctly on host B. The `$DISPLAY` environment variable must be set to the display of host A.